# Pohlig-Hellman: While solving in a subgrp, why is multiplication done mod the parent group's $p$ while the exponent is expanded as per $p_i$ of subgrp

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field, pohlig-hellman

In the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm, we take a Discrete Log Problem (DLP) in a group & solve it in subgroups $p_1^{n_1}$, $p_2^{n_2}$, $p_3^{n_3}$ etc & then combine it with the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).

The original DLP is $\bmod p$ & the order $p -1 = n = p_1^{n_1} * p_2^{n_2} * p_3^{n_3} .... $

When we are solving for a subgroup $p_1^{n_1}$, we frame number of coefficients of $x$ based on the max value $x$ can take i.e. $p_1^{n_1} - 1$

For example, if we are solving for $3^4$, then we frame $x$ as

$x = c_0 + 3c_1 + 3^2c_2 + 3^3c_3$

$x$ has 4 coefficients here ($c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$ & $c_3$) because the max value of x is [$p_1^{n_1} - 1$] (because it's $\bmod p_1^{n_1}$)

However, when we actually solve for finding the coeffs of $x$ for subgroup $p_1^{n_1}$, we do the calculations with $\bmod q$, instead of $\bmod p_1^{n_1}$. Why is that?

For e.g. if we take the example [here](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m5410/phexam.html): When they calculate $8006^{2025} = 1$ for subgroup $2^2$, this is actually calculated as $8006^{2025} \bmod p$ rather than $\bmod p_1^{n_1}$. It's the same in all the calculations. Why is this? Shouldn't it be done $\bmod p_1^{n_1}$

When we are finding $x = x_1 \bmod {p_i}^{n_i}$, we are doing calculations $\bmod q$ instead of doing them $\bmod {p_i}^{n_i}$.

**EDIT:** Or an alternate question could be this - the operations of the subgroup is always going to be $\bmod p$ rather than $\bmod {p_i}^{n_i}$.  Considering that, then why are the 3 congruence equations we get for the 3 subgroups also not $\bmod p$. Why are they $\bmod 4$, $\bmod 81$ & $\bmod 25$?

**EDIT2:** Based on various answers, I have boiled down my question to one line

**While multiplication in the subgroup is being done modulo p, why are exponents in the subgroup expanded modulo $p_i$**?

Is there any theory explaining this?

Comment: Sorry misread, 4.3 better http://math.ucdenver.edu/graduate/thesis/dreiff.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka - I couldn't find anything in 4.3 which talks about why the coeffs of x for $\bmod {p_i}^{n_i}$. are calculated  $\bmod q$ instead of calculating them $\bmod {p_i}^{n_i}$.

Comment: mod $q$ is a prime power.

Comment: Taking the example you linked, you have a prime $p=8101$ and $q=p-1=8100$ a product of powers of small primes. $q$ is the order of the multiplicative group mod $p$. The group operation is multiplication mod $p$, and if you want to find the order of an element in this group, you have to use therefore exponentiation mod $p$. Numbers you multiply or take exponents of, you have to reduce modulo $p$, only their exponents you can reduce mod $q$.

Comment: @j.p. - The operations of the subgroup is always going to be $\mod p$ rather than $\mod {p_i}^{n_i}$.  Considering that, then why are the 3 congruence equations we get for the 3 subgroups also not $\mod p$. Why are they $\mod 4$, $\mod 81$ & $\mod 25$?

Comment: The congruence equations are equations in the exponent, hence $\bmod q$.

Comment: @j.p - Why is it that exponents are $\mod q$. Also here we aren't even doing them $\mod $, we are doing them $\mod {p_i}^{q_i}$ etc? Is there any theory behind these 2 things?

Comment: Easy example: Take $p=7$, then the multiplicative group has order $q=6$, as $0$ is excluded as only non-invertible element. If you multiply the elements, you reduce mod $p$. If you take exponents mod $p$, like $3^9\bmod 7$, then you can reduce *the exponent* mod $q$, as $x^{p-1}\bmod p = 1$ for prime numbers (unless $p$ divides $x$): $3^9 = 3^{9\bmod 6} = 3^3 \bmod 7$.

Comment: @j.p. - Thank you. That makes sense. What about the 2nd question. The congruence equations are in equations in the exponent. Why then are those equations formed mod factors of the exponent (${p_i}^{a_i}$) rather than $\mod q$?

Comment: $q$ is a big number, and the results modulo the prime power divisors of $q$ can be assembled to yield the result modulo $q$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. So you have just to find a method of solving the discrete logarithm (= finding the exponent) modulo a prime power (in the exponent), to solve the full problem. Your linked webpage shows you an easy way for this.

Comment: @j.p. From your example, I got how $a^x \bmod p$ can be reduced as $a^{x \bmod q} \bmod p$ where $q=p−1$. However what happens in the case $a^x \bmod {p_1}^{n_1}$ - how will x be reduced there? Why is it $a^{x \bmod {p_i}} \bmod p_1^{n_1}$ & not $a^{x \bmod p_i^{n_1}} \bmod p_1^{n_1}$?

Comment: I hope $a^x \bmod p_1^{n_1}$ is a typo for $a^{x \bmod p_1^{n_1}} \bmod p$, or that you understand now why it has nothing to do with $a^x\bmod p$.

Comment: @j.p. - it was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [question's example](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m5410/phexam.html) asks finding the solutions $x$ of equation $a^x\equiv b\pmod p$ given $p$, $a$, $b$, with $p=8101$, $a=6$, $b=7531$. It's stated $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_{8101}$, but it's meant $\mathbb Z_{8101}^*$, which is the [multiplicative group modulo $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). The $^*$ (or $^\times$) means we use the multiplicative law of the [ring of integers modulo $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), or equivalently that we form the group by keeping the elements of the ring that are invertible, as mandated by a [group axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition). In particular, that implies we exclude $0$, and any $c$ with $\gcd(c,p)\ne1$.

That Discrete Logarithm Problem is modulo *prime* $p$, a simplifying special case¹. The aforementioned group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is thus² [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group). It has [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $n=p-1$, that is $n$ elements which we can designate by their integer representative in range $[1,n]$. The order of any element $c$ of that group, defined as the smallest integer $\ell>0$ with $c^\ell\equiv1\pmod p$ thus divides the order $n$ of the group. We are told that $a$ is a generator, which means the order of $a$ is $n$, and we can check this³.

We are now in the situation where we can apply the [general Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm&oldid=995062207#The_general_algorithm) algorithm as stated in Wikipedia, with their $\mathbb G$ of order $n$ our $\mathbb Z_p^*$ of order $n=p-1$, their $g$, $h$ and $e_i$ our $a$, $b$, and $n_i$ :

- The first step in that algorithm is factoring $n$ into $n=\prod{p_i}^{n_i}$, that is $8100=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot5^2$. For each $i$ we'll form a [subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ where we solve a sub-problem.
- Each of this sub-problems is $\left(a^{n/({p_i}^{n_i})}\right)^{x_{p_i}}\equiv b^{n/({p_i}^{n_i})}\pmod p$ (per the [linked example's notation](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m5410/phexam.html), which uses $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_5$ where Wikipedia uses $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$). Each of this sub-problem is in the (cyclic) subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ generated by $a^{n/({p_i}^{n_i})}\bmod p$, of order ${p_i}^{n_i}$. We solve each separately using [Pohlig-Hellman for group of prime-power order](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm&oldid=995062207#Groups_of_prime-power_order). Calculations involving elements of a subgroup are within the main group, thus in $\mathbb Z_p^*$, thus modulo $p$. Calculations involving exponents (in particular, the solution $x_{p_i}$ ) are modulo the subgroup order, that is ${p_i}^{n_i}$.
- Then we join the solutions $x_{p_i}$ in a [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) step, where the coprime moduli are the ${p_i}^{n_i}$, which product is our $n=p-1$.

In summary, all calculations involving a multiplication by $a$ or $b$ are modulo $p$, so as to be in the group $\mathbb Z_p^*$. Same for raising $a$ or $b$ (or a product of powers thereof) to some power. Only operations involving an exponent (that is the integer defining to which power we raise such combination of $a$ or/and $b$) is made modulo something other than $p$: the group order or a subgroup order, thus modulo $n$ where $n=p-1$, or modulo some divisor of $n$.

---

> why are the 3 congruence equations we get for the 3 subgroups also not $\bmod p$. Why are they $\bmod 4$, $\bmod 81$ & $\bmod 25$?

Because they are congruence modulo the *orders* ${p_i}^{n_i}$ of the 3 subgroups of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ generated by the 3 elements $a^{n/({p_i}^{n_i})}\bmod p$. Relations (multiplicative) *in* these subgroups of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ would be modulo $p$.

---

> While multiplication in the subgroup is being done modulo $p$, why are exponents in the subgroup expanded modulo $p_i$?

For any [finite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_group) $(\mathbb G,*)$ of order $r$ (that is, with $r$ elements), for any $x\in\mathbb G$, it holds⁴ $\underbrace{x*x\ldots x*x}_{r\text{ terms}}=x^r=1$, where $1$ is the neutral of the group.

Therefore, for any integers $s$ and $t$, $x^s*x^t=x^{s\cdot t\bmod r}$, where $s\cdot t\bmod r$ is computed over integers regardless of the group's nature and it's group law $*$. That's why exponents are computed modulo the group order.

When we consider a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ (thus where computations are modulo $p$) that has order $p_i$ (as in this sub-question) or ${p_i}^{n_i}$ (as in the overall problem), that subgroup is a group of order $r=p_i$ or $r={p_i}^{n_i}$. When working in that subgroup, we can thus reduce exponents modulo $r$.

Notice that the order $r$ of a finite subgroup always divides the main group's order, here $n=p-1$.

---

> solve it in subgroups ${p_1}^{n_1}$, ${p_2}^{n_2}$, ${p_3}^{n_3}$ etc

It's important to be precise here: we are solving an equation $a^x\equiv b\pmod p$ in a subgroup of order ${p_i}^{n_i}$ of the main group $\mathbb Z_p^*$. Therefore, equations related to exponents are stated (and solved) in the ring of integers modulo ${p_i}^{n_i}$ noted $\mathbb Z_{{p_i}^{n_i}}$ ; while equations related to exponents in the main group are in the ring of integers modulo $n=p-1$ noted $\mathbb Z_n$.

---

Picky note on notation:

For integer $m>0$, the notation $u\equiv v\pmod m$ is read as “$u$ (is) congruent to $v$ modulo $m$” or sometime “$u$ equal(s) $v$ ... modulo $m$”, as a shortcut for “(the representative of) $u$ equals (the representative of) $v$ in the [ring of integers modulo $m$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n)”. That notation means (equivalently):

- that $m$ divides $u-v$
- that $u-v$ is a multiple of $m$
- that the remainder of the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) of $\left\lvert u-v\right\rvert$ by $m$ is $0$
- that exists integer $w$ with $u=(w\cdot m)+v$

The notations $u=v\bmod m$ and $v\bmod m=u$, in which $\bmod$ is an operator combining two integers into an integer, are respectively read as “$u$ equal(s) ... $v$ modulo $m$” and “$v$ modulo $m$ equal(s) $u$”. Both mean (equivalently):

- that $u\equiv v\pmod m$ as defined above, *and* $0\le u<m$
- that $u$ is

  - the remainder in the Euclidean division of $v$ by $m$, when $v\ge0$
  - $m-1-((-u-1)\bmod m)$, otherwise

When hearing ”$u$ equals $v$ modulo $m$” (without a discernible pause), or seeing $u=v\mod m$ (with extra spacing on the left of $\bmod$ due to the use of `\mod` rather than `\pmod` or `\bmod`), there can be an ambiguity about if $0\le u<m$ is meant, and that maters in some crypto applications. When we write $c=m^e\bmod n$ in RSA, we positively assert $0\le c<n$. For consistency, we want to write $\forall k\in\mathbb N,\;2^k\equiv2^{k\bmod 42}\pmod{43}$, rather than $\forall k\in\mathbb N,\;2^k=2^{k\bmod 42}\bmod 43$, which has counterexample $k=6$.

---

¹ When solving for $a^x\equiv b\pmod m$ in the most general case of a composite $m$, the outer step could be to factor $m$ as $m=\prod{m_j}^{k_j}$ with $m_j$ prime; then solve each of the problems $a^{x_j}\equiv b\pmod{m_j^{k_j}}$; then join the solutions. Here there's a single $m_1$ (one special case), and $k_1=1$ (another special case).

² The converse is not true, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314846/35016).

³ The standard technique is ensuring $a^{n/p_i}\not\equiv1\pmod p$ for each prime $p_i$ dividing $n$. Here $n=p-1=8100=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot5^2$ thus $p_i\in\{2,3,5\}$, and neither of $6^{4050}\bmod8101$ , $6^{2700}\bmod8101$ , $6^{1620}\bmod8101$ is $1$, thus $a=6$ indeed is a generator.

⁴ [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), in the form $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ for prime $p$ and $a$ not divisible by $p$, is precisely a restriction of that statement with $(\mathbb G,*)$ the group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ with $p$ is prime.

Comment: `No, and the question's issue stems from that confusion.` - sorry - this was actually a mistake in writing down my thoughts. I know that the original DLP is $\bmod p$ & order of the group is $q$. I will edit the Q right away, Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: If my question had to shorted to one line, it would be this line from your answer - "Calculations involving exponents are modulo the subgroup order" - why is this? What is the theory behind this?

Comment: Re your edited answer - here the subgroup is of order $p_i^{n_i}$ as you have written in one of the other paras. So shouldn't we be reducing the exponents modulo $p_i^{n_i}$ & not $p_i$ as being done in the solution?

Comment: @user93353: I read this [solution](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m5410/phexam.html) as deriving it's $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_5$ modulo $4$, $81$ and $25$, that is modulo ${p_i}^{n_i}$, not $p_i$; then joining them with the CRT modulo $n=5\cdot81\cdot25$. It's only in the determination of the individual $x_{p_i}$ that arithmetic modulo $p_i$ is used. Specifically, each $x_{p_i}$ is split into $n_i$ components each in $[0,p_i)$, found individually. That's similar to the loop of step 3 of Wikipedia's Pohlig-Hellman for group of prime-power order (link in the question).

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it finally. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

The group we are considering is $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, so every operation in that group (that includes operations in subgroups of that group) follow the same rule, namely computation mod $p$.

When we look at a subgroup with small order $p_i^{n_i}$, all computations are still in the original group $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. But then we know that for each element $g$ in that subgroup, we have $g^{x}=g^{x\bmod p_i^{n_i}}\bmod p$.
In other words, operations in the group must abide by the given group structure and are conducted modulo $p$. But, in the exponent, you can now compute modulo $p_i^{n_i}$ (instead of $p-1$).

Comment: Is there any theory or proof about why for the subgroup, it is $g^{x}=g^{x\bmod p_i^{n_i}}\bmod q$?

Comment: Actually, the definition of the order of a (sub)group says that raising an element of that (sub)group to its order gives you 1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory) For special cases, there is also the following theorems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem (for Pohlig-Hellman we use the fact that $\varphi(q)$ has small factors)

Comment: How do Fermat's Little Theorem or the others show that $g^{x}=g^{x\bmod p_i}\bmod p_i^{n_i}$? Fermat's theorem is $g^{p-1}=1\bmod p$

Comment: @user93353: see new note 4 in my answer for relation between $\underbrace{x*x\ldots x*x}_{r\text{ terms}}=x^r=1$ where $r$ is the group order and Fermat's little theorem. $g^x\equiv g^{x\bmod p_i}\pmod{{p_i}^{n_i}}$ (with the notation fixed) does not hold, counterexample $p_i=3$, $n_i=2$, $g=2$, $x=4$. We have $2^4\bmod9=7$ when $2^1\bmod9=2$.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks, you are right, now it's called $p$.

Comment: @user93353 Let $g$ be some group element with order $r$ (I'll use $r$ for simplicity, in your case $r=p_i^{n_i}$). $x$ can always be written as $x=a+k\cdot r$ for $a\in\{0, \dots, r-1\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ ($a$ is basically what happens, when you compute $x\bmod r$, that means $a=x\bmod r$). Then, $g^x=g^{a+k\cdot r}=g^a\cdot (g^r)^k=g^a\cdot 1=g^{x\bmod r}\bmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

as we know that DLP is finding x in : ${y \equiv g^x (mod p)}$, we use pohlig-hellman when order of group G is B smooth, when B is relatively small. We assume that g is a generator.
In real cases when order of g is quite large, we use one of the subgroup generated by g. for simplicity we assume g is a generator. so solution for x is available.

- from group theory value of x lies in {1,...,p-1} and this cyclic group(field) is having  , it as many cyclic subgroup and if it has subgroup, order of subgroup divides order of Group, (Lagrange's Theorem)
- Now we're trying to find the value of ${y \in G}$ with base g. i.e, y=gx.
- rather than finding by normal process, we factor p-1 and try to find out if x contains in the subgroup generated by that factor.
- for ex in case of ${6^x \equiv 8 (mod 13)}$, we have ${p-1=12 = 2^2 \times 3}$
- Here ${x \equiv x_0+2x_1}$, and algorithm is to find out if smallest x lies in subgroup generated by 4 as we want to solve it by CRT.
- subgroup generated by 4 is {4,3,12,9,10,1} and 3 is {3,9,1}
- we can see that 3 is the common factor which gives us the answer.
- when we are finding ${g^x}$ we should obviously work mod p. But when we write the x with base as one of it's factor which is 4 or 3 and apply CRT, we only work to the mod 4 or mod 3 here. i.e, ${x \equiv x_0+x_1q+...+x_{r-1}q^{r-1} (mod q^r)}$, where q can be {3,4}
- From basic **Group Theory** we know that there is a Group isomorphism $${\phi(G) \rightarrow C_{q_1^{e_1}} \times...\times C_{q_r^{e_r}}}$$ where ${C_{q^{e}} }$ is a cyclic group of prime power order ${q^e}$
- The projection of ${\phi}$ to the component ${C_{q^{e}} }$ is given by
- $${\phi_q :G \rightarrow C_{q^{e}}  , f \mapsto f^{N/q^e} }$$ here N=p-1.
- Now the map ${\phi_q}$ is a group homomorphism so if we have ${y = gx}$ in G then we will have ${\phi_q(y) =
  \phi_q(g)^x}$ in ${C_{q^e}}$ . But the discrete logarithm in ${C_{q^e}}$ is only determined modulo ${q^e}$. So if we could solve
  the discrete logarithm problem in ${C_{q^e}}$ , then we would determine x modulo ${q^e}$.
- Doing this for all
  primes q dividing N would allow us to solve for x using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.
- In summary suppose we had some oracle O(g, y, q, e) which for  ${g,y \in C_{q^e}}$ will output the discrete logarithm of y with respect to g.
- Looking at other's comments, it is better to revisit CRT.
- when we have two relative prime m,n, we have
- [1] ${f: Z_{mn} \mapsto Z_m \times Z_n}$ defined by ${f(x)=(x(modm), x(modn)}$is a ring isomorphism.
- [2] ${\phi(mn)=\phi(m) \phi(n)}$
- [3] ${f^{-1}(a,b)= an(n^{-1} (mod m)) + bm(m^{-1}(mod n)) (mod  mn) ) }$
- With [2] we can see that final answer is always reduced to (mod mn), due to the closure property of Group.
- We know that for any x, (x mod mn) mod m = x mod m,
  CRT can be used to compute exponentiation in ${Z_{mn}}$ faster. Since ${Z_{mn}}$
  is isomorphic to the ${Z_m \times Z_n}$ product structure, instead of computing ${a^e mod mn}$,
  we can compute ${a^e mod m}$ and ${a^e mod n}$ which gives ${a^e}$ in ${Z_m \times Z_n}$. Then we can
  use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to recover ${a^e mod mn}$.
- Since the complexity of exponentiation is cubic in the size of the modulus, assuming that m and n are half of
  the size of mn, exponentiation in ${Z_m}$ costs 1/8 of the exponentiation price in ${Z_{mn}}$,
  as well as exponentiation in ${Z_n}$. Since applying the Chinese Remainder Theorem is
  quadratic, we speed up the exponentiation by a factor of 4.

Comment: `But when we write the x with base as one of it's factor which is 4 or 3 and apply CRT, we only work to the mod 4 or mod 3 here. i.e, ${x \equiv x_0+x_1q+...+x_{r-1}q^{r-1} (mod q^r)}$, where q can be {3,4}` - why? Why do we write x based on q rather than based on p? while we are calculating the multiplications modulo p, why is q used for x? Is there any theory explaining this - that is the crux of my question

Comment: @user93353, I've added one more paragraph in my answer at the end.  Let me know if you still have doubts.